# Multiple Foursquare 'save' buttons on one page

Tags: foursquare, microformats

I am working on a site that displays a list of venues and would like to add a Foursquare 'save' button for each venue in the list. Is it possible to show multiple Foursquare 'save' buttons on a single page? I've tried creating multiple vCard blocks (one for each venue) and inserting a 'save' button in each block but the locations are not being picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting the source of the `widgets.js` and  `widgets.asyncbundle.js` I discovered that setting the`data-context` atribute of the 'Save to Foursquare' button to the ID of the VCard will link these two. Like so:

```html
<div id="hcard-Station-Amsterdam-Centraal" class="vcard">
    <span class="fn">
        <span class="given-name">Station Amsterdam Centraal</span>
    </span>
    <div class="adr">
        <div class="street-address">stationsplein 15</div>
        <span class="locality">Amsterdam</span>, 
        <span class="region">Amsterdam</span> , 
        <span class="postal-code">1012AB</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="hcard-Jaarbeursplein" class="vcard">
    <span class="fn">
        <span class="given-name">Jaarbeursplein</span>
    </span>
    <div class="adr">
        <div class="street-address">Jaarbeursplein</div>
        <span class="locality">Utrecht</span>, 
        <span class="region">Utrecht</span>, 
        <span class="postal-code">3521AL</span>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="https://foursquare.com/intent/venue.html" class="fourSq-widget" data-context="hcard-Station-Amsterdam-Centraal" data-variant="wide">Save to foursquare</a>
<a href="https://foursquare.com/intent/venue.html" class="fourSq-widget" data-context="hcard-Jaarbeursplein" data-variant="wide">Save to foursquare</a>
```

But for the fact that this isn't documented, it may be changed in the near future.

Comment: Be sure to use class="vcard" (not class="vCard" as in 4q documentation)

Comment: It worked nice for my blog. I have a list of places to visit and they are working nice now. Hope de 4sq team to build a better solution in the future like a hidden text field as the value of the text field been the URL of the venue. That could reduce a lot effort for the page authors.

Comment: This works great. Just a note, if you're an organization, the vcard formatting is a little different: class="org fn" on a parent element, and then class="organization-name" on the child element that contains the organization name. Using this, I was able to get our two museum locations to show up with the relative 4Square Save buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with "data-vid":

```
 <!-- Place this anchor tag where you want the button to go -->
<br />
All In PartyRadio Studio<a href="https://foursquare.com/intent/venue.html" class="fourSq-widget" data-vid="50575a55e0e27c7feb062116">Save to foursquare</a>
<br />
Sing Sing Music Hall<a href="https://foursquare.com/intent/venue.html" class="fourSq-widget" data-vid="4d47d1fe2165721ebe9ac0d7">Save to foursquare</a>
<br />
Retro Klub<a href="https://foursquare.com/intent/venue.html" class="fourSq-widget" data-vid="4d437d813616b60c2764dac2">Save to foursquare</a>
<br />
Tisza Dokk<a href="https://foursquare.com/intent/venue.html" class="fourSq-widget" data-vid="4f73231de4b0e3a99689cc61">Save to foursquare</a>
<br />
Zöld Zsiráf Kultúrpart<a href="https://foursquare.com/intent/venue.html" class="fourSq-widget" data-vid="4ffad97ef13633933ececa5f">Save to foursquare</a>

<!-- Place this script somewhere after the anchor tag above. If you have multiple buttons, only include the script once. -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
  (function() {
    window.___fourSq = {"uid":"606"};
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'http://platform.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js';
    s.async = true;
    var ph = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    ph.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ph);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The in-progress docs for the save-to-foursquare widget are accessible @ https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/widgets. They'll be cleaned up over time, but should be good enough to help this and future widget-related questions =).

In particular, documentation about the "data-context" attribute you need will be pushed to the linked page soon.

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention the `data-context` attribute for multiple buttons on a page, so referring to that and saying 'but should be good enough to help this and future widget-related questions' is not helping..

Comment: The documentation will be updated soon to include that attribute

Comment: Ok, didn't know you are working for 4sq, anyway, mentioning the documentation as a solution when you know that it doesn't cover the attribute is still misleading. Add to your answer that it will be described in the documentation soon and I will undo my downvote.